# Retrieve nested list VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop, nested-loops

I am a bit rusty in dealing with Lists. i have declared 2 public lists

```
Public Shared individualDetails As New List(Of String)
Public Shared catList As New List(Of List(Of String))
```

An Add button to add strings into `individualLists`.

```
Protected Sub btnAddLevel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddLevel.Click

    individualDetails.Add(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value)
    individualDetails.Add(txtAvailability.Text)
    individualDetails.Add(txtRemarks.Text)

    catList.Add(individualDetails)

End Sub
```

Users are able to do multiple adds to add to `catList`.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To catList.Count

        For x As Integer = 0 To individualDetails.Count

             MsgBox(individualDetails(x))

        Next x
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am having trouble with the inner for-loop. I did a debug, and i know `individualDetails` will contain 6 items if I add twice.

May I ask how can I add multiple lists to `catList` rather than a combined list into `catList`? Am I adding the lists wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catList` is a container for lists. You have only one list in the container, `individualDetails`. Your `btnAddLevel` event handler keeps adding new entries to that one list, rather than making new lists.

`individualDetails` shouldn't be a `Public Shared` variable; it should be local to your event handler:

```
Protected Sub btnAddLevel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddLevel.Click
    Dim individualDetails As New List(Of String)

    individualDetails.Add(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value)
    individualDetails.Add(txtAvailability.Text)
    individualDetails.Add(txtRemarks.Text)

    catList.Add(individualDetails)

End Sub
```

You will need to change your debugging code to see the lists; use something like

```
For i As Integer = 0 To catList.Count - 1
    Dim individualDetails = catList(i)

    For x As Integer = 0 To individualDetails.Count - 1 

         MsgBox(individualDetails(x))

    Next x
Next i
```

There are other improvements to the code you could make, but this should get you going.

Comment: Hi @prprcupofcoffee, great. it is working now, however i did a minor change to the loop. i added in .count - 1 , else it will run out of subscript. thanks for the direction!

Comment: I figured you'd encounter that :) Part of the process!